# Spring MVC 5.0 which HandlerMapping used as default HandlerMapping while developing annotation driven web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 4.x when we use more than two `HandlerMapping` then we have to configure `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` explicitly in configuration file but in Spring 5.0 they removed `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, so which `HandlerMapping` is used as default  `HandlerMapping` now.

Answer (score 1):

See the section [3.1.13 New HandlerMethod-based Support Classes For Annotated Controller Processing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-in-3.1-handler-method-controller-processing) of the Spring Docs.

The important are first lines which say that since Spring 3.1 there is introduced a new set of classes replacing the deprecated ones.

The one you probably look for is [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html).